# How to prevent window dimensions from displaying when using chrome.windows.update?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When using `chrome.windows.update` to resize a window, the new dimensions are displayed in a small white box in the upper right corner of the document. Can this be prevented?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That white box with dimensions is a feature of the Chrome developer tools. It shows up when the window's dimensions are changed while the developer tools are opened.

Close the developer tools for the specific tab, and the box won't show up any more.

If you don't want to close the developer tools, you're out of luck for now. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=260637 (it's marked as Fixed, but the reported issue has *not* been fixed yet).